# Regularization tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

It seems, the word regularization has two major meanings: one in statistical analysis, and the other in the context of divergent series. Can we somehow solve this issue?

Comment: I guess regularization in stats means smoothing out the data points somehow eg moving average?

Comment: Currently there are 274 questions tagged [tag:regularization], 51 of them are [also tagged optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularization+optimization), 37 of them are [also tagged divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularization+divergent-series). There is also a tag called ([tag:summation-method]) - which seem like a reasonable tag for regularization of divergent series.

Comment: @CalvinKhor [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)

Comment: We need to regulate the regularization tag usage.

Comment: `regularization.st` and `regularization.nt` perhaps?